# MacBook Pro 13 Mid 2010 Internet Recovery stuck

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery, internet

I am trying to recover my MacBook Pro 13 Mid 2010 from the internet. After sometime it starts to show these two photos. I don't know what it means. None of the keys responds.

I restarted my system after waiting for 15 min. Is there anything I am supposed to do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime problem is solved. I don't know what solved it. But I let it continue the 2nd time. After 30 min it ended up with an installation error, mentioning something about memory access problems. I restarted the whole thing again. Everything was the same, but this time it worked :). Now the next part, where it all started. Install Windows 7 on Boot Camp :).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are installing Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

This screen is telling you that there is no keyboard or mouse detected and you must connect one via USB or Bluetooth to begin using the computer.

Unless you had issues with the keyboard and mouse before installing the operating system it seems very unlikely that there is actually anything wrong with the computer but that a simple reboot would probably fix the missing devices and if not reinstalling the operating system would definitely solve this issue.